# Question about ideal transformer

Tags: power, transformer, rms, core

Let's say that an ideal transformer has a rating of 500/125 V, 10 kVA. The source voltage applied to the primary winding is 525 V (rms). The load that is connected to the secondary winding consumes the nominal power of the transformer with power factor 0.9 (which is inductive). The core losses are ignored. How can I calculate the voltage of the secondary winding?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost definitely your homework I'm doing here.

Be that as it may, assuming no losses in the transformer, most of that question is a red herring. The voltage developed on the secondary side of the the transformer will be higher than rated by the same ratio that the primary is. Divide through and then multiply. I'm really not going to give you the answer.

Follow on questions will probably ask you what the secondary and primary amperage is. Calculate secondary side amperage based on 10 kva - power factor doesn't matter, because the question *said* at the nominal rating, which is already an apparent power. Once you have that, it will probably want to know what the real and reactive load quantities are. *Then* you can break out your power triangle and figure it out. Primary side amps are just going to be secondary amps divided by the transformer ratio.